# Count Ways To Place Letters Into Alternating Color Titles

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

Given the letters 'BBNNRRQK'. If we want to place each letter within each title with the following restrictions:

1. Without replacement
2. The BBs have to be of opposite color
3. K must be between the RRs

Example of valid combinations:
RBBKQNNR 
BNQNRKRB

How many possible combinations are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we count all combinations (without restriction 2 and 3), we have $\frac {8!}{2 \times 2 \times 2}$ combinations.

When we apply restriction n°2, we apply a factor $\frac{4}{7}$ to this number.

When we apply restriction n°3, we apply factor $\frac{1}{3}$ to this number.

Both restrictions are independant, final result is $\frac {8!\times 4}{2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 7 \times 3} $

Edit : one word to explain : symetry.

Comment: I think you must explain how to obtain $4/7$ and $1/3$ to OP

Comment: if you fix where one of the Bs is located, you have 7 other possibilities for the other one, 4 of them satisfy condition 2 and 3 don't. In the same idea, if you assign three tiles where the Rs and the K lie, only of the three positions of the Rs and the Ks will satisfy condition 3.